# Does iterator violate stack/queue data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, iterator

As we know in Java each class that implements `Collection` interface should implement `Iterator<E> iterator()` method.

`Stack` and `Queue` are parts of collection hierarchy and implement this method as well. So we can write something like this:

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
//    Deque stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
stack.add( "1" );
stack.add( "2" );
stack.add( "3" );

Iterator i = stack.iterator();
while ( i.hasNext() ) {
  Object o = i.next();
  if ( o.equals( "2" ) ) {
    i.remove();
  }
}
```

My concerns here are:

1. Is it ok that we are able to delete elements from the middle of the stack/queue?
2. Is it ok that stack/queue should "show" only one element (last in stack and first in queue) but actually we are able to get all of them without calling "pop","enqueue" methods?

Comment: Don't use raw types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the strictest sense, `Stack` and `Queue` should not allow iteration over it's element but the only reason this restriction exists is to justify the existence of these data structures. As per [sgi](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stack.html)

> Stack does not allow iteration through its elements.
>
> This restriction is the only reason for stack to exist at all. Note that any Front Insertion Sequence or Back Insertion Sequence can be used as a stack; in the case of vector, for example, the stack operations are the member functions back, push_back, and pop_back. The only reason to use the container adaptor stack instead is to make it clear that you are performing only stack operations, and no other operations.

While some implementations follow this, for example `std::stack` in C++ does not expose `iterator`, other implementation provide iterators as a feature. [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) in java is built on top of `Vector` which implements `iterator`. [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) is built on top of `Collection` which requires `iterator` to be implemented. To answer your questions

> Is it ok that we are able to delete elements from the middle of the stack/queue?

Yes. The underlying implementation will make sure that your stack/queue is in a consistent state after the deletion.

> Is it ok that stack/queue should "show" only one element (last in stack and first in queue) but actually we are able to get all of them without calling "pop","enqueue" methods?

Yes it's a feature of the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok that we are able to delete elements from the middle of the
>   stack/queue?

Yes since stack/queue both will keep their contract even after deleting , after all the methods exposed by stack/queue manipulate the internal implementation which is used for the deletion

> Is it ok that stack/queue should "show" only one element (last in
>   stack and first in queue) but actually we are able to get all of them
>   without calling "pop","enqueu" methods?

Yes you are not violating either contract since the remove is done throw iterator interface of the element not queue or stack